# leveldb example not working on windows : Error LNK2029

Tags: c++, leveldb

In order to test leveldb, I tried to reproduce the leveldb's [example](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html) on VS 2008.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "leveldb/db.h"

int main()
{
    leveldb::DB* db;
    leveldb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options,"D:\dev\tools\tmp",&db);
}
```

I have **included** leveldb/include directory and **linked** libleveldb.lib.

**Result** :

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   leveldb::Status __cdecl leveldb::DB::Open(struct leveldb::Options
>   const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class
>   leveldb::DB * *)"
>   (?Open@DB@leveldb@@SA?AVStatus@2@ABUOptions@2@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAPAV12@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol public: __thiscall leveldb::Options::Options(void)"
>   (??0Options@leveldb@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**

Use [levelDb-portable](https://github.com/zhangyafeikimi/LevelDB-portable) from ***zhangyafreikimi***